# SFF chatroom not showing user location when profile get shared due to font colour

Tags: bug, design, chat

I just changed my name on the site and shared it on [The Quill and Tankard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38869458#38869458), but my location was not visible due to the font colour:

[image]

But it's still there and visible if I select that area

[image]

I did same on [The Screening Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38869385#38869385) and it worked fine :

[image]

Current colur code is #FFF (white) on SFF, if we can change it to anything else, maybe to #222 (Black) like Movies & TV chatroom, then it can work :

[image]

Else any other color except white.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed this before. +1.

Comment: @Randal'Thor and fix is too small

Comment: further investigation shows that this is because the onebox is inheriting the default 'message' text color, which assumes the dark blue background; presumably this will involve changing the rendering of the onebox to explicitly color the location text black

Comment: @KutuluMike which is not that hard science either

Comment: by that I presume you have access to the onebox generation code to know precisely how difficult such a change would be?